# Resetting React component State

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a component that stores state of an array of objects like:

```
 [
  { id: 'all', title: 'Select all', icon: '', selected: false },
  { id: 'overview', title: 'Overview', icon: 'user-check', selected: false },
  {
    id: 'about',
    title: 'About',
    icon: 'info-circle',
    selected: false,
    partSelected: false,
    children: [
      { id: 'profile', title: 'Profile', selected: false },
      { id: 'howToOnboard', title: 'How To Onboard', selected: false }
    ]
  },
  { id: 'interviewGuide', title: 'Interview Guide', icon: 'comments', selected: false }
]
```

My component takes this array as a prop and sets it using setState hook i.e.

```
const SelectionMenu = ({ menuData, translations }) => {
 
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState(menuData);
  
  const updatedMenu = menuData.map(a => ({...a}));
```

i then manipulate a copy of this array(updatedMenu) and set it later on i.e.

```
    setMenuState(updatedMenu);
```

How can I reset the state back to the initial menuData? it always seems to be maintained...

Comment: You mean that menuData has changed ? Or you're just searching for `setMenuState(menuData)` ? ... Not very clear IMO

Comment: Where do you get the initial state information from?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "reset" your menu state you still have your prop here :

```
const SelectionMenu = ({ menuData, translations }) => {
```

So you can call this to "reset" the date aka put back the initial data :

```
setMenuState(menuData)
```